# Trouble with got: 408 Status Propagation Issue in Async Requests

Tags: node.js

There's a problem. When using got (get) in a loop, for example, 1000 domains at once, if at least one of the domains receives a 408 response, then all subsequent domains will also be 408.

It seems that this error applies to the entire client at once.

Any thoughts on how this can be fixed?

I tried to set the timeout for each request (without a global config) - the problem was not solved.

Example: parse 1000 domains, first domain - status success, second domain - 408 AND ALL THE FOLLOWING 408 instantly.

*Client*:

```
const got = require('got');
const Logger = require('./logger');

let iconvLib = require('iconv-lite');

class Client
{
    constructor(url, data = {}, timeout = 6000, headers = {}) {
        this.url = url;
        this.data = data;
        this.timeout = timeout;
        this.customHeaders = headers;
        this.response = {};
        this.logger = new Logger();
    }

    getJson() {
        return JSON.parse(this.getBody());
    }

    getBody() {
        let response = this.getResponse();

        const contentType = response.headers['content-type'];
        const matches = contentType.match(/charset=([^;]+)/);
        let encoding = matches ? matches[1] : 'utf8';

        if(encoding === 'windows-1251') {
            encoding = 'win1251';
        }

        let body = iconvLib.decode(Buffer.from(response.body), encoding);

        //console.log(body);

        return body;
    }

    getHeaders() {
        return this.getResponse().headers;
    }

    getStatusText() {
        return this.getResponse().statusMessage;
    }

    getStatus() {
        return this.getResponse().statusCode;
    }

    getResponse() {
        return this.response ?? {};
    }

    async head() {
        const config = this.getConfig();
        if(Object.keys(this.data).length !== 0) {
            config.searchParams = this.data;
        }

        try {
            this.response = await got.head(this.url, config);
        } catch(e) {
            this.response = this.handleErrors(e);
        }

        return this;
    }

    async post() {
        const config = this.getConfig();
        if(Object.keys(this.data).length !== 0) {
            config.body = this.data;
        }

        try {
            this.response = await got.post(this.url, config);
        } catch(e) {
            this.response = this.handleErrors(e);
        }

        return this;
    }

    async get() {
        const config = this.getConfig();
        let params = '';
        if(Object.keys(this.data).length !== 0) {
            const sign = this.url.includes('?') ? '&' : '?';
            params += sign + this.serialize(this.data);
        }

        config.responseType = 'buffer';

        try {
            this.response = await got.get(this.url + params, config);
        } catch(e) {
            this.response = this.handleErrors(e);
        }

        return this;
    }

    handleErrors(e) {
        const response = e.response ?? {};
        const errorsStatusMap = {
            'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS': 310,
            'ERR_NON_2XX_3XX_RESPONSE': 403,
            'ECONNREFUSED': 404,
            'ECONNRESET': 404,
            'ENOTFOUND': 404,
            'ERR_INVALID_URL': 404,
            'ETIMEDOUT': 408,
            'EAI_AGAIN': 408,
            'Z_BUF_ERROR': 507,
            'Z_DATA_ERROR': 507,
            'EPROTO': 526,
            'EHOSTUNREACH': 0,
            'HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN': 0,
            'ENETUNREACH': 0,
        };

        if(e.code) {
            response.statusCode = errorsStatusMap[e.code];
        }

        if(e.name) {
            response.statusText = e.name;
        }

        if(!response.body) {
            response.body = '';
        }

        if(!response.statusCode && response.statusCode !== 0) {
            response.statusCode = 0;
        }

        return response;
    }

    getConfig() {
        return {
            timeout: {
                request: this.timeout,
            },
            retry: {
                limit: 0,
                maxRetryAfter: undefined,
            },
            https: {
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            },
            headers: Object.assign({
                'Connection': 'close',
                'User-Agent': this.getUserAgent(),
                'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0',
                'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': 'Windows',
                'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
                'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
                'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
                'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
                'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': 1,
                'Dnt': 1
            }, this.customHeaders)
        };
    }

    getUserAgent() {
        return 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36';
    }

    serialize(obj, prefix) {
        let str = [],
            p;
        for (p in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                const k = prefix ? prefix + '[' + p + ']' : p,
                    v = obj[p];
                str.push((v !== null && typeof v === 'object') ?
                    this.serialize(v, k) :
                    encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(v));
            }
        }

        return str.join('&');
    }
}

module.exports = Client;
```

*How i use client*:

```
async makeHttpsRequest(domain) {
    const client = new Client('https://' + domain);
    await client.get();

    return client;
}
```

*And use this request in init function for my parser*:

```
let parsers = [];
for(const domainItem of domainList) {
    parsers.push(new Parser(domainItem['domain'], domainItem['id'] ?? 0));
}

parsers = await Promise.all(parsers.map(parser => parser.init())); // <- I call makeHttpsRequest here in parser.init();
```

Answer (score 1):

408 is timeout. You are probably sending too many requests at once. Stagger them a bit or limit the concurrency. Check out for example the package [`p-limit`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-limit).

Also remember that one rejected promise will reject the entire `Promise.all` promise immediately. Maybe use `Promise.allSettled` or add a `try`/`catch` in your `makeHttpsRequest` function.

Comment: ```const limit = pLimit(10);

        let parsers = [];
        for(const domainItem of domainList) {
            parsers.push(limit(() => this.parseDomainMethod(domainItem['domain'], domainItem['id'] ?? 0)));
        }```

I tried it. For some time everything was fine, out of 1000 domains, 100 were adequate, then 408 fell to the end. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you follow my second advice too? Maybe one of them still returns 408, but that should be okay, as long as you made sure it won't abort the whole operation in that case.

Comment: Yes, i add `allSettled`